# Invalid Mapping with Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I've i run into an exeption while trying to use Hibernate 4.3.x with java on netbeans, the exption is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at teste.ConectaJavaDB.main(ConectaJavaDB.java:17)
Caused by: org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Could not parse mapping document from resource model/Equipe.hbm.xml
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processHbmXml(Configuration.java:3764)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processHbmXmlQueue(Configuration.java:3753)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processMetadata(Configuration.java:3741)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1410)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1844)
    at conexao.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:25)
    at conexao.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:14)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.DuplicateMappingException: Duplicate class/entity mapping model.Equipe
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MappingsImpl.addClass(Configuration.java:2837)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder.bindRoot(HbmBinder.java:178)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processHbmXml(Configuration.java:3761)
    ... 7 more
```

(the second error says about duplicate mapping, but i dindt mapped twice)
by reading the exeption, it's possible to see that the problem is in the mapping  xml of the class Equipe, the XML contains:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping package="model">
  <class name="model.Equipe" table="equipe">
    <id name="id" type="int" column="ID" >
      <generator class="increment"/>
    </id>
    <property name="nome"/>
    <property name="dataNascimento"/>
    <property name="email"/>
    <property name="enderecoWeb"/>
    <property name="fone"/> 
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

And the class:

```
    package model;
    import java.util.Date;

    public class Equipe {

        private int id;
        private String nome;
        private Date dataNascimento;
        private String email;
        private String enderecoWeb;
        private String fone;

   [..]getters and setters[..]
```

Hibernate.cgf

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">app</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">app</property>
    <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

    <mapping class="model.Jogador"/>
    <mapping resource="model/Equipe.hbm.xml"/>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

I can't seem to find the error, the hole code is posted on Bitbucket above, thanks!

Hole code: https://bitbucket.org/angelorodem/progapl_ii_272278_2015/src

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You invoked `configuration.configure()` twice. Remove the second invocation, or just copy paste the code below:

```
    Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
    configuration.configure();
    serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();
    sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
    return sessionFactory;
```

Comment: Worked like a charm!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
  <mapping class="model.Jogador"/> (remove this)
<mapping resource="model/Equipe.hbm.xml"/>
```

try this:

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

<mapping resource="model/Equipe.hbm.xml"/>
```

Comment: As i commented on @smoggers post you can indeed put both mappings
but thanks for the reply!